# Expand/ Collapse more than one ExpansionTile on clicking on any of them

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing a design in which I have to use two ExpansionTiles next to each other, I have implemented the two ExpansionTiles with the required data inserted, but I need to be able to  Expand/ Collapse both of them together if I clicked on one of them.
Right now they are Expanding/ Collapsing separately without any issue, but I need them to be connected to each other any time the user tries to Expand/ Collapse any of them.

Can I achieve this on flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this by-

> declare a bool type variable with false value.
> pass this variable to isExpanded property for both ExpansionTile
> Write following code for each ExpansionTile's onExpansionChanged method:

```
setState(() {
   <var_name here> = v;
}) ;
```